# Сделать post запрос посредству tor

Tags: node.js, axios, tor

Как сделать post запрос axios, с подключением Tor, я делаю так:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent')
const httpsAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(`socks://127.0.0.1:9050`)

let payload = {
   goodUrl: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=670284533441,
   location: 1,
   sign: '193a5838e50ad4f042224997f96acc08',
}

const example = await axios.post(`https://front.superbuy.com/crawler/`, payload, {
   httpsAgent,
   headers: {
     'referer': 'https://www.superbuy.com/',
   }
});
```

В ответ я получаю эту ошибку: `Request failed with status code 403`

Comment: 403 - forbidden, отсутствие прав доступа.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков может я как то не так делаю запрос?

Comment: Может и не так делаете :) но во первых вы запрос сам не показали, во вторых куда его отправляете, в третих протокол.....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да хоть куда, простой пост запрос, соединяя м тор, подходе нельзя отправить запросы пост, потому что я пробую через гет, работает, запросы идут через тор

Comment: А это хоть где принимает пост запросы?) Может вы покажете пример который не работает а не нечто абстрактное?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ok, я исправил код )